# Semantic equivalence of synchronized method and Semaphore(1, true)?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, jvm, semaphore

Are the following two method definitions semantically equivalent? Why? Why not?

Version A:

```
private static synchronized void foo() {
    bar();
}
```

Version B:

```
private static Semaphore available = new Semaphore(1, true);
private static void foo() {
    available.acquire();
    try {
        bar();
    }
    finally {
       available.release();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, except

- that the first one synchronizes on the class, and that there might be other parts of the code that synchronize on the same class.
- that the semaphore could be fair, whereas synchronization is not
- that the thread blocked in semaphore.acquire could be interrupted, causing an InterruptedException to be thrown. Your code doesn't compile as is: you must handle this exception somehow, whereas you don't have to using synchronized.

Comment: Also, a semaphore could be released from another thread than the one that acquired it. (see [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) javadocs)

Answer (score 3):

I would say **no** - Java `synchronized` block is not guaranteed to preserve order, i.e. it is not fair.

`new Semaphore(1, true)` is fair (`true` argument).